# Sublime text 3: Using the same tab stop twice without cloning the word

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext-snippet

I'm currently using the same tab stop twice in order to select two elements that are linked together.  If the feature these two control is not needed, then neither one needs to be there.

That said, the tab stop does indeed select both areas it is supposed to, "$1:{ }", but when used - it shows the "mw_hide" in both spots.

What I am trying to do is use that tab stop, but keep both words.

So it should show "mw_hide" and "isMobleEle" when the tab stop is selected, rather than showing "mw_hide" in both places.

Before anyone says it - naming them both "mw_hide" is not an option in this case unfortunately.

All that said, does anyone know if this is actually possible?

(Code below)

> ```
> <snippet>
>   <content><![CDATA[  <!-- ********** FW - Full Hero ********** -->
>   <div class="isMobile ${1:mw_hide}">
>       <!-- Place A -->
>       <div class="grid1">
>             <a href="URL" coremet="This${2:StayMobile}">
>                 <img src="//img/setA/${1:isMobleEle}" alt="${3:AltTextHere}" />
>             </a>
>       </div>
>   </div>]]></content>
>     <!-- Optional: Tab trigger to activate the snippet -->
>     <tabTrigger>MOB</tabTrigger>
>     <!-- Optional: Scope the tab trigger will be active in -->
> </snippet>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [this is not possible](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html#mirrored-fields). Instead, use different field id numbers ("tab stops"). If two different fields have the same identifier number, anything typed in that field will be identical in both places, unless you're altering it with a [substitution](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html#substitutions).

Comment: Eh, that's what I thought.  I've pretty much pushed the snippets to their limits already - though I figured someone else might have tried it and succeeded somehow. Using some RegEx tactics almost worked, but not quiet.

I appreciate your response, and thanks for confirming it